# How to create a icon from a picture on Linux?

Tags: icons

On Ubuntu Linux, though I don't think it's about which distro.

I have a picture...

How can I create my own icon from the picture?

Comment: What kind of icon? By definition, and icon is just a picture...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ convert winamp-ncrow.png -resize 32x32 winamp-ncrow.ico 
geee: ~/.icons/known
$ file winamp-ncrow.*
winamp-ncrow.ico: MS Windows icon resource - 1 icon
winamp-ncrow.png: PNG image data, 128 x 128, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced][1]
```

**convert** is one of the many tools included in the ImageMagick package. It is very popular and will be without doubt found among the packages of your favorite distribution. apt-get install imagemagick (or what have you)

For reference: 
http://www.imagemagick.org/

---

### Image Files:

[winamp.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He6cv.png)

Comment: hmm, is convert something you find by default on most linux distros, or something you need to install?

Comment: I forgot to mention what app that was. how stupid. just a second

Comment: "By default" is very relative. I mean, some distros will let you install "Desktop" and "Home Video", which will usually result in a pretty bloated installation with lots and lots of unexplored stuff. Surely, Imagemagick is in one such category, perhaps "Photography" or whatever. I have no idea to be honest, but I'm pretty sure most distros include it on the _first distribution cd_, if those are still commonly used. :)

Comment: true, but now the answer is better, since we don't assume convert is installed ;p. This is almost a stock question I ask when someone suggests a application whose name dosen't give away its origin ;p

Comment: It's a fair question. But Imagemagick is -really- worth looking into, if you haven't come across it already.

Answer (score 2):

[GIMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP) can export .ico files.

A simple search would had given you this answer; it's usually easier to try that first if you know what you need.